# scikit-image fails to install

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to install the `scikit-image` package on my Windows 7 64-bit machine with python 3.5. While installing scikit, the requirements are met:

```
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=1.8 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=2.1.0 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=0.4.0 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.1.0 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=1.8->scikit-image)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from PyWavelets>=0.4.0->scikit-image)
```

But in the end, the installation fails with:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 114: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Command "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\scikit-image\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3hy8fcuv-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\scikit-image\
```

I already tried:

```
pip install -U wheel
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U scipy
```

and also upgrading pip itself, nothing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual solution was to type `chcp 65001` before the install command. This changes the default character encoding of the console to UTF-8, then it worked.

Comment: How can I reset this mode?

Comment: Open new console?

Comment: This crazy magic number helped me to compile scikit-learn on my Windows 10. Thanks! That's a real shame that compilation depends on system settings

Answer (score 2):

I know now's a bit late(r), but I just had the exact same problem. The solution for me was to install the wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) instead.

TBH, I don't know what they do differently, why they work and by whom they are.

Download the correct version there. E.g. for python 3.5 you want the version containing `35`. Currently, this is `scikit_image‑0.13.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl` and right below that is the 64 bit version of that.

Install it by running `pip install C:\users\you\downloads\the_wheel_you_downloaded`.