# Installing scikit-image

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

I am installing scikit-image using `pip install scikit-image`. I get this error:

> Failed building wheel for scikit-image

What is the command to install scikit-image using wheel?

I see references to `pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` but I didn't understand what this does.

Comment: Could you paste the error you got here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scikit-image fails to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226362/scikit-image-fails-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

First do this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then install scipy

Then install numpy

```
pip install numpy
```